# In Bot Framework Composer turn.recognized.Intents contains only one intent

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I managed to make Luis return all intents in a query by adding

```
      "predictionOptions":{
    "includeAllIntents": true
  }
```

to the recognizerFile: {dialogName}.en-us.lu.dialog

In the emulator I see the json that comes back containing several intents under *turn.recognized.Intents*. But if I make the bot send a message with the content of that collection then it just sends a collection with a single item, the top scoring intent.

Am I missing some configuration here that makes the deserialization of the Intents property to fail?